# Overriding external binary resource doesn't update its content

Tags: c++, qt, resources, qml

I'm using external binary resources to set the graphical interface of my program.

Everything works when I switch from **redTheme.rcc** to **blueTheme.rcc**: my interface is updated.

Now let's say I want to update my **redTheme.rcc** file from the outside of my program. I am able to detect that the file has been overridden by using the [QFileSystemWatcher](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html) class. Here's what I do to update its content:

```
QResource::unregisterResource("redTheme.rcc");
QResource::registerResource("redTheme.rcc");
```

Both commands return `true`. However, my graphical interface is not updated. It seems that the content of my resource is not overridden.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: try [Q_CLEANUP_RESOURCE(redTheme)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#Q_CLEANUP_RESOURCE).

Comment: It seems to only work with internal resources, such as my **qml.qrc** which contains my controllers and views. My custom objects are contained in my external binary resources.

Comment: Looks like a Qt bug, you should report it. A temporary workaround would be to switch to another resource and then back.

Comment: Switching from **redTheme,rcc** to **blueTheme.rcc** and vice-versa works. However, even if they are overidden, their content do not change.